# Reactjs App Where can I define my Layout?

Tags: reactjs, layout

I am new to ReactJs and I am not sure where and how should I define Layout for components. Specifically I want my SideBar Header and Footer remain sticky and using react-router-dom I want to mount rest of the components at appropriate places whenever needed (click on sidebar item)? So should I render multiple components together or there is a another way to first define the layout and then render components at predefined places ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read through some guides on getting started with React. We're happy to answer specific questions, but the above is basically "tell me how rendering in React/React-Router works" which is a bit too much scope for a single question.

Comment: can you direct me with some good guides that specifically target that problem I have searched but not found the specific guides

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic components, use css to lay them out on different pages and render them at once by calling them under render of that main big component. This would make could modular and non-redundant too.

Refer this github , I found it good for referral.

> https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp

For the quick layouts you can use bootstrap templates. ( This can help you get started)

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/